# Reading binary file to a string but the types are mixed

Tags: c, file-io, syntax, binaryfiles

I'm trying to read a binary file but when I read its characters it doesn't looks like it's formatted with `char` type so for example the numbers don't have their ASCII value instead, their actual value but letters does have ASCII value.

Why is that?

Also, when I create a binary file, it doesn't hold all those `'\0'` padding, nor the `\x` behind every number, what are those and why do they show up?

This is how I'm reading the file:

```
FILE * fp = fopen("file.bin", "rb");
char foo[20];
fread(foo, sizeof(char), 20, fp);
```

Which I can see in VS, fills `foo` with this:

```
[0]: 5 '\x5'
[1]: 0 '\0'
[2]: 0 '\0'
[3]: 0 '\0'
[4]: 97 'a'
[5]: 66 'B'
[6]: 67 'C'
[7]: 100 'd'
[8]: 101 'e'
[9]: 6 '\x6'
[10]: 0 '\0'
[11]: 0 '\0'
[12]: 0 '\0'
[13]: 97 'a'
[14]: 97 'a'
[15]: 66 'B'
[16]: 84 'T'
[17]: 82 'R'
[18]: 121 'y'
[19]: 4 '\x4'
```

Is there a way to read all characters such that all will hold ASCII values? Is there a way to not read the `\0` and `\x`?

Comment: The `\x` is an inseparable  part of `\x4`.  It is the representation of value `4`.  `\x` has nothing to do with the data in `foo[]` nor data in the original file.  It is an artifact of the VS viewer.

Comment: I see. How come the numbers don't have ASCII values though? and what's with the `\0` padding? @chux

Comment: Value like `4` (and values 0-31,127) do not have a _printable_ ASCII symbol - they are control characters.  The VS viewer is showing those as `back_slash`, `x`, `number`.  Further: how do you _know_ the viewer is showing ASCII for all 256 different possible bytes?  Recall ASCII is only defined for codes 0-127.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @chux said, the `\x` that VS is displaying to you is an inseparable part of the `char` representations that VS is presenting to you.  It is trying to be helpful by providing a form that can be used directly in C source code as a `char` literal.  For example,

```
char c = '\x4';
```

It is also (separately) giving you the numeric value of each `char` (expressed in decimal form).

> How come the numbers don't have ASCII values though?

You said it yourself: you are reading a *binary* file.  Typically that means numbers are represented in a binary form, not a *formatted* form.

> and what's with the \0 padding?

In the data you presented, that goes together with numbers being in binary form.  The zero-value bytes appear not to be padding, but rather parts of 4-byte numeric (little-endian) representations of your numbers.  Thus, the number `6` is represented by four bytes, having values `6`, `0`, `0`, `0`.

Depending on how the data are written, however, there *could* be padding between some members.  Dealing with issues such as this is one of the joys of working with binary data formats.  To read the data correctly you need a precise definition of its form.

Comment: I wasn't provided with a precise definition... So how would a larger number be represented here? say 999999? would it be `9`,`9`,`9`,`9`,`9`,`9`?

Comment: If you're stuck reverse-engineering a binary format then you have my sympathy.  As for value `999999`, if the numeric fields indeed are represented in 32-bit, little-endian form, then (1) they will always consist of exactly 4 bytes, and (2) `999999` (decimal) would be represented as bytes `'\x3f'`, `'\x42'`, `'\x0f'`, `'\0'` (decimal numeric values: `63`, `66`, `15`, `0`).  That is associated with the fact that the hexadecimal representation of decimal `999999` is `0xf423f` (== `0x000f423f`).

Comment: Oh converting that into an integer doesn't seem trivial, it's reversed and mangled... Does the decimal numeric value help in converting the number to be an integer?

Comment: @kuhaku, yes, it is byte-wise reversed, in that the bytes run from least-significant to most-significant.  That's what "little-endian" means.  It's the standard 32-bit integer format for Intel CPUs.

Comment: "Does the decimal numeric value help in converting the number to be an integer?"  It helps *you*, inasmuch as you can determine the binary or hexadecimal representation from the decimal one.  It's next to meaningless to the computer.